# How do I access inhereted member in List if I added them trough abstract class

Tags: c#

My example code would looks something like this. I have two classes A and B and they both inherit abstract class. 
At one point I want to make a list that is List so that I can add both classes A and into it. Lets say that later at some point I want to make a new list that is List and I want to add only A class to it. How do I do that? Since I can't access member of my A class?

```
abstract class Abstract
{
    public string X;

    public Abstract(string x)
    {
        X=x;
    }
}

class A : Abstract
{
    public int Number;

    public A(string x, int number):base(x)
    {
        Number = number;
    }
}

class B : Abstract
{
    public int Age;

    public A(string x, int age):base(x)
    {
        Age = age;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Abstract> abstractList = new List<Abstract>();

    abstractList.Add(new A("Something", 1111);
    abstractList.Add(new B("Something2", 2222);

    //Now at some point I want just to add A class to new list
    List<A> AList = new List<A>();
    for (int i=0;i<abstractList.Count;i++)
    {
        if(abstractList[i] is A)
            AList.Add(new A(abstractList[i].x, abstractList[i].?)); //How do I do this part?
    }

}
```

I've marked in comments part that confuses me the most. Even if you don't want to just give me the answer could you point me in direction where I should look?
I feel like I'm missing a big part of how it works here.

Comment: You declare a list with your base type, `List<Abstract>`. So the program only knows it's got `Abstract` elements, it doesn't know if it's type `A` or `B`. So you'll need to look at the type. You've got the first part, `if(abstractList[i] is A)`, you'll just need to cast after that. `var a = (A)abstractList[i]` or similar

Comment: You can use [`OfType<A>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8) on the list to only get back the objects of the type `A`.

Comment: Thanks! You've helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`OfType<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8) on the list to only get back the objects of the type `A`.

```
AList = abstractList.OfType<A>().ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.